# this.model inside directives in angular

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

I have a doubt about how to consult models of controllers in Angular using this.model

If I have the next controller:

```
angular
.module("myApp", [])
.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl)
.directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myCtrl(){
  var vm = this;

  //model
  vm.myModel = "whatever";
}

//my directive    
function myDirective(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       // here!
      // how can I acces to the myModel model if it was defined with 'this'
    }
  }
}
```

If my model was like this:

```
$scope.myModel
```

I could read it with scope.myModel inside myDirective, **but with "this (vm.myModel)" how can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is passed in as the scope parameter.

```
scope.myModel
```

In the case of the `vm` syntax, it becomes another layer on the scope paramater. For instance:

```
scope.vm.myModel
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get any parent controller of a directive by using

```
angular.element.parent().controller();
```

Here is a working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/22226/

Using this code, if I changed the vm in the controller to something else, I do not need to change the directive's code.